# export 'default' (imported as 'router') was not found in './router'

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Hi i want to implement vue router in another file but i got one error: "export 'default' (imported as 'router') was not found in './router'

Thanks in advance.

```
// Import
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueMeta from 'vue-meta'
import { router  }from './router'
import App from './pages/app'

// Config
Vue.use(VueMeta)
window.axios = axios
Vue.config.productionTip = false

// Start Vue.js
new Vue({
  router,
  ...App
})
```

router/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>' }

let routes = [
    // Login
    { path: '/login', component: Bar },

    // Errors
    { path: '*',  component: Bar  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    base: 'public', 
    mode: 'history',
    routes
})
```

Comment: Your `router/index.js` doesn't `export` *anything*? But no, the error message doesn't fit your code

Comment: you need to export the router, something like `export default router = new VueRouter({`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to import `router` from your `/index.js` file, you need to actually export it. Just add `export` before `const router =` in your `router/index.js` file. So it looks like:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>' }

let routes = [
    // Login
    { path: '/login', component: Bar },

    // Errors
    { path: '*',  component: Bar  }
]

export const router = new VueRouter({
    base: 'public', 
    mode: 'history',
    routes
})
```